# Does indexed column with millions of different values make sense?

Tags: oracle, index, index-tuning, oracle-12c

I noticed that one of my queries was pretty slow, taking about two seconds to execute.

This is the slow query:

```
SELECT EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_EVENTTYPE FROM EVENT WHERE (EVENT_ID = :1  AND EVENT_RESULT = :2  )
```

The index used was created like this:

```
CREATE INDEX "INDEX_EVENT_DATETIME" ON "EVENT" ("EVENT_DATETIME", "EVENT_ID")
```

The execution plan shows an `index skip scan` because obviously the `EVENT_DATETIME` column is not in the where clause.

So at first I thought I would create a second concatenated index on the table for the columns `(EVENT_ID, EVENT_RESULT)` but then I noticed that the column `EVENT_DATETIME` has 18,702,145 distinct values. Of a total of 18,722,706 rows.

There are 4 different queries happening regularly on this table. All of them except one have the `EVENT_DATETIME` column in the where clause but all of them have `EVENT_ID` in the where clause.

So my assumption is that the index as it is currently being used doesn't make the queries more efficient.

Is it correct that a concatenated index on the columns `(EVENT_ID, EVENT_DATETIME`) would be more useful?

Comment: What's the table's Primary Key  ? I suppose "EVENT_ID" should be the PK.

Comment: Perhaps you should run DBMS_STATS.REPORT_COL_USAGE on interested columns in that table and understand how they have been used in the query (as captured by optimizer). That could help as well.

Answer (score 2):

For b-tree index , the more distinct values the better.

Index skip scan doesn't seem to be an efficient access method in your case because the first column in the index has high cardinality. It works opposite to "regular" index usage like index range scan or index unique scan  where you want the first column to be the most discriminating.  It's hard to say if in this particular case full table scan would behave better without trying (`FULL` or `NO_INDEX` hints can do the job) .

No doubt, for the query in  question index on `event_id,event_date` is much better than on `event_date,event_id`.

It's hard to tell without seeing your other queries, but I think you may not necessarily need to have composite indexes.  Each column, event_date and event_id, appear to be have very few duplicates (if any) .  Then having two indexes, one on `EVENT_DATE` and another on `EVENT_ID` will work better than having multiple concatenated indexes - even if a composite index is covering for some queries, the engine will have to do only one or two extra lookups .

Answer (score 1):

> Does indexed column with millions of different values make sense?

Sure, why not? Won't a primary key index have a distinct value for each row? A covering index for a query can still be useful even if the underlying columns have a high number of distinct values. Such indexes can also be useful when doing range scans. If you want all of the data for one day then I don't see why it matters how many distinct values there are.

> So my assumption is that the index as it is currently being used doesn't make the queries more efficient.

The EXPLAIN PLAN shows the index being used. That means that the Oracle query optimizer thinks that the index makes the query more efficient. If you think that's not correct then try testing the query with a [NO_INDEX hint](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABHJBIB). Does it get more or less efficient?

> Is it correct that a concatenated index on the columns (EVENT_ID, EVENT_DATETIME) would be more useful?

You're asking this question but you haven't given us the queries or any statistical information about the other columns. The best thing that you can do is to try testing out different options. Why guess when you don't have to? Create multiple indexes and see which index Oracle uses. Use the `NO_INDEX` hint as necessary if you really want to see the difference in queries. With all of that said, if the `EVENT_ID` column is far more selective than `EVENT_DATETIME` then maybe your other suggested index will be more useful for the query in the question.